# Why is this not a infinite loop?

Tags: c

```
int main() {
int i,j=6;
for(;i=j;j-=2)
printf("%d",j);
   return 0;
}
```

This piece of code gives output 642 
please explain me why this loop doesn't run infinitely and stops when j is non-positive

Comment: Why should it infinite? o___O

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: Remember, = is not a comparison.

Comment: okay thanks, now i got it , non zero i is true and as soon as i becomes 0 it's false.Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `j` becomes `0` the expression `i=j` evaluates to `0`. Hence, the loop terminates.

Note that if `j` were to start as negative number ( e.g. `-1` )or as an odd number (e.g. `5`), then the condition will never evaluate to `0` and will result in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

In C `0` is evaluated as `false` and non-zero as `true`. The controlling expression `i = j` becomes `false` when `j = 0` and the loop will terminate.
The loop will go infinite if you change your program to

```
int i, j = 6; 
i = j;
for(; i == j; j -= 2, i = j)
    printf("%d",j);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(;i=j;j-=2)
```

This is a for loop with no initial code, which on every iteration will assign `j` to `i` as the condition check, then at the end decrement `j` by 2. Note that the *value* of an assignment expression is the value assigned, hence your `i = j` expression will yield the value of `j`.

So, what will happen cycle by cycle is as follows:

- Assign `i` = 6, `j` = 6
- Nothing for the initial for loop statement
- `i` = `j` (6)
- Print `j` (6)
- `j -= 2`
- `i` = `j` (4)
- Print `j` (4)
- `j -= 2`
- `i` = `j` (2)
- Print `j` (2)
- `j -= 2`
- `i` = `j` (0)
- The above expression evaluated to 0, hence false, hence the loop terminates.